# Set class to a cell and get value after that with JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I have this table:

```
<table>
<tr> <td>first</td> <td style="display:none"> 1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>second</td> <td style="display:none"> 2</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>third</td> <td style="display:none"> 3</td> </tr>
</table>
```

*note: i need the second column invisible

I would like to select only one row and  after that  with a button get the value of the invisible column's selected row.for that:

1. When I click a cell of the first column, I want to add to the next cell (the invisible one) a class, maybe with `.toggleClass("flag");`
2. then I would like to get the value of the cell that has that class and put it in an `alert();`

I've tried to add a click event listener to the cell, so you can send `this` as parameter, so How can I add the class to the next cell?

Comment: What have you tried? From your question, you have all the keyword that are similar to the name of the jQuery function that you should use (*with the exception of `value`*)...

Comment: So add a click event, remove the class from the rows, add a class to the current row, read what you want.

Comment: *"When I [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) a cell of the [first](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) column, I want to add to the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) cell (the invisible one) a [class](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), maybe with .toggleClass("flag");"*

Comment: Please what you have tried and let us know what did not work as expected ... and how you were expecting it to work.

Comment: I've tried with a function to set the second column by its index:
function x(obj){
$(obj).index()+1.toggleClass("flag");}

and to get it  something like
 var id= $('#table tr td').find(".flag");

Comment: I added a click event, but how can I manage events Indexes, if I click a cell, how can I add the class to the next one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it close to what you probably wanted (in your comment). Try using jQuery `.next()` to get the next sibling element:

```
 function x(obj){ 
     $(obj).next().toggleClass("flag"); 
 }
```

It would help *a lot* next time if you provide a code example (e.g. in a JSFiddle).